# Android Studio Flutter Tag mismatch - can't build project

Tags: android, windows, flutter, tags, mismatch

After format pc (Windows 10)
install Flutter and Android studio etc.
when install Android SDK I got error "Tag mismatch!"
and can't build project give me errors all error has this word "Tag mismatch!"
then I format again this time download fine but still not build project

[When try build project get error like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sOSR.png)

[I try download additional SDK I got an error again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAHsT.png)

[Also get error like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMXSG.png)

Getting error also build normal android application (not flutter)
Uninstall fully Android Studio and Flutter few times and reinstall again SSD HDD still get same problem.
but when use VPN sometimes it works.
Internet connection Download and Upload: ~45mbps
Before format I haven't any problem like this. 2 days searching but not found the solution event don't know what is problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the WiFi USB Adapter I'd been using. For some reason,  it prevented gradle from being successfully downloaded. Changing the adapter solved the problem.

Comment: I downgrade windows 10 to older version then it worked fully then updated latest version again now worked.
I guess when I formatted pc there has some certification problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I though it was network issue, reset the wifi, still the issue persisted.

Later on I manually installed Flutter and that too only a single version of it was compatible, and to find this specific Flutter version I literally had to apply binary search algorithm based on the error message.

Android has got to take care of this shit. Developers don't deserve to take care of the shit that belongs to someone else. This should be a black box for us, or a reasonably informative, functioning abstract layer has to be provided to developers.